# Change the definition of "Completed"

Tags: eclipse, bugzilla, mylyn

I'm using Eclipse Helios with the MyLyn plug-in, connecting with an external Bugzilla server.

I prefer not to have the system show me "Completed" tasks.  Otherwise, the panes quickly fill up with completed stuff.

Unfortunately, when I mark a bug in Bugzilla as "RESOLVED," MyLyn equates that with "Completed."  Therein lies the rub.  For me, Bugzilla tasks are not completed until they are "CLOSED."  With our particular workflow, there are still things I have to do after marking a Bugzilla task as "RESOLVED."

Is there some way to tell the Bugzilla connector in MyLyn to equate "CLOSED" with "Completed," instead of "RESOLVED?"

Peace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define [custom workflow configuration](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Bugzilla_Connector#Custom_Transitions) for your Bugzilla repository in Mylyn.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer.  Because it is the correct answer.  Unfortunately, I was never able to make that work and we've moved away from Bugzilla to another tool.